# Show image in JSP (Spring 3 java configuration)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm studying Spring java configuration now and I want to show an image in my .jsp page. I've searched a lot. This question is popular but still no answers helped me. Image still doesn't appear. I would be really glad is someone could help me.

My directory tree:

```
-src
--main
---java
----com
-----app
------controller
-------MainController.java
------springconfig
-------WebConfig.java
--webapp
---resources
----images
-----11706.jpg
----styles
---WEB-INF
----view
-----home.jsp
----web.xml
---index.jsp
```

MainController.java

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class MainController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String loadHomePage(Model m) {
    m.addAttribute("name", "CodeTutr");
    return "home";
  }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.app.controller")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
  }

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.enable();
  }

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
  }

}
```

home.jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, ${name}!!!</h1>
    <img src="/resources/images/11706.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.app.springconfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Sorry for so many code snippets. Hope it'll help solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another solution, Spring has it's own tag library, which allows you to output the URL relative to the path of your app.

At the beginning of the JSP file you must include:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

And then use the tag to create image URL:

```
<img src="<s:url value="/resources/images/11706.jpg" />" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try using the `<c:url var="imageUrl" value="/resources/images/11706.jpg">` pattern. You would then have `<img src="${imageUrl}"></img>`. Alternatively, use a div to hold the image, and use css to load it into the div. You'll also need to import the jstl taglib using `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` at the top of your page, and you'll need to ensure that you have the jstl as a module dependency for this to work.

Comment: where should the resources folder should be in web app folder?

Comment: In this example, yes, in the root of the webapp folder. `resources` is a particularly bad name though -- because it's a concept used by maven to mean something different. I think a more modern name would be something like `assets`. However, JSP is utter nonsense anyway, so whatever you do with it is basically wrong.

Comment: So what is correct way?
I stuck in displaying images

Comment: Your web content should be static html containing divs with static IDs. Javascript should interact with REST servers to pull down json data which is then inserted into the dom in an appropriate manner. CSS should style the whole thing.